# tab.openerTabId undefined in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this code in background script of my Firefox WebExtension, but it prints : `"OPENER ID: undefined"` each time new tab is created:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log("OPENER ID: " + tab.openerTabId);
});
```

What is the problem? This code works well in Chrome, and in documentation it says that `openerTabId` property is supported in Firefox.

And yes, openerTab is still present when new tab is created (new tab is created by clicking on some link in openerTab).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get openerTabId in Firefox WebExtensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411682/how-to-get-openertabid-in-firefox-webextensions)

Answer (score 0):

#### Supported in Desktop Firefox as of Firefox 57

As of [Firefox 57](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility), the desktop version of Firefox supports [`tabs.Tab.openerTabId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Type).

#### Not supported in Firefox for Android

Firefox for Android [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility) `tabs.Tab.openerTabId`

For detail on a workaround which will give you at least some information, please see my answer to: [How to get openerTabId in Firefox WebExtensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42422254/3773011)

#### Not supported prior to Firefox 57 (original answer)

The problem is that Firefox [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility) [`tabs.Tab.openerTabId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Type). The [compatibility notes for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Firefox) explicitly state [emphasis mine]:

> 'openerTabId' is **not supported**.

If you really need this information, you can, mostly, track it yourself using various events: [How to get openerTabId in Firefox WebExtensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411682/how-to-get-openertabid-in-firefox-webextensions)

If this is functionality you desire to see as part of the WebExtensions API, I suggest you [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) to track its implementation.

Comment: I implemented it manually by tracking all tabs and their states. Shame they didn't implement such trivial thing themself, although bug is filed a long time ago.

Comment: it seems that it is now supported, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @toto_tico Thanks for bringing to my attention that this should be updated. I've done so. I've also voted to close the question as a duplicate of [the other question you commented on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42411682/3773011). If you could do the same, I'd appreciate it. Once closed, I'll delete this answer, as it's really just a short version of my answer there. I'm not sure why this question wasn't closed around when I answered the other one.