# How to get openerTabId in Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've developed a Chrome extension, and trying to port it to Firefox using Firefox WebExtensions.

Here is the problem I'm facing. In my extension, I need to use `chrome.tabs.Tab.openerTabId`, which is not supported by Firefox WebExtensions (See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Firefox)).

I've come up with a workaround, to get `openerTabId` myself, by querying the active tab in current window:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    // tabs has only one element, which is the one I just opened
});
```

But it doesn't work, because the result of this query, is *the tab I just opened, instead of the one before I click New Tab button*.

Now I want to query the active tab before I click New Tab button, but I didn't see any parameter in `chrome.tabs.query()` like `lastFocusedTab`.

Could this be done by `chrome.tabs.query()`? Or is there any other way to do this?

Possible duplication: [tab.openerTabId undefined in Firefox WebExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315422/tab-openertabid-undefined-in-firefox-webextension). Unfortunately, this one is not solved :-(.

Comment: openerTabId is now supported by mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Supported in Desktop Firefox as of Firefox 57

As of [Firefox 57](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility), the desktop version of Firefox supports [`tabs.Tab.openerTabId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Type).

#### Not supported in Firefox for Android

Firefox for Android [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility) `tabs.Tab.openerTabId`

If you want your extension to be compatible with Firefox for Android, you will have to track this information yourself. You can track the opener tab ID for tabs that are opened by the user through clicking a link. When a new tab is created by JavaScript, you can guess that it was done by JavaScript in the active tab, but you can't know. You can do this through a combination of tracking the currently active tab, listening for new tabs to be created, and listening to see that the reason the new tab was created was because the user clicked a link.  This can be done by listening to:

- [`tabs.onActivated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onActivated) to track the currently active tab
  This is fired prior to `tabs.onCreated`, so you will need to keep a record of the prior active tab. This will be needed for cases where the newly opened tab is immediately activated. Obviously, you also need to account for cases where the new tab is not immediately activated.
- [`tabs.onCreated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onCreated) to determine when a new tab is created.
- [`webNavigation.onCommitted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCommitted) to look at the [`transitionType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/transitionType) to see that the new tab was actually created from a `link`, as opposed to just happening to be the active tab when the user opened a new tab from a bookmark, etc.

For reference, these are the events which fire when the user clicks on a link (`<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">`):

```
Content event: mousedown  on: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">  contentMessageUI.js:16:9
Content event: mouseup    on: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">  contentMessageUI.js:16:9
Content event: click      on: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">  contentMessageUI.js:16:9
tabs.onActivated                  ->  arg[0]= Object { tabId: 8, windowId: 0 }
tabs.onHighlighted                ->  arg[0]= Object { tabIds: Array[1], windowId: 0 }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: undefined } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onZoomChange                 ->  arg[0]= Object { tabId: 8, oldZoomFactor: undefined, newZoomFactor: 1, zoomSettings: Object }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete", url: "about:blank" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: undefined } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "loading" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onCreated                    ->  arg[0]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate    ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:blank", timeStamp: 1487869034364, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8 }
webNavigation.onErrorOccurred     ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:blank", timeStamp: 1487869034368, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, error: "Error code 2152398850", tabId: 8 }
webNavigation.onCommitted         ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:blank", timeStamp: 1487869034377, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, transitionType: "link", transitionQualifiers: Array[0] }
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate    ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487869034380, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8 }
webRequest.onBeforeRequest        ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "150", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487869034382, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8 }
webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders    ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "150", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487869034384, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, requestHeaders: Array[6] }
webRequest.onSendHeaders          ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "150", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487869034387, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, requestHeaders: Array[6] }
webRequest.onHeadersReceived      ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "150", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487869034416, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, responseHeaders: Array[11], 2 more… }
webRequest.onResponseStarted      ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "150", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487869034420, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, responseHeaders: Array[11], 2 more… }
webRequest.onCompleted            ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "150", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487869034429, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, responseHeaders: Array[11], 2 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "loading", url: "http://www.example.com/" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
webNavigation.onCommitted         ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487869034538, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8, transitionType: "link", transitionQualifiers: Array[0] }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 8 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 8, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded  ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487869034710, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8 }
webNavigation.onCompleted         ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487869034715, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 8 }
```

It appears that the `transitionType` will also be `link` when the tab is opened through JavaScript (assuming the user has permitted it). The following are the events when a new tab is opened by `window.open('http://www.example.com');` (simulated by executing that in the DevTools console for a content page, after permitting popups from that domain):

```
tabs.onActivated                  ->  arg[0]= Object { tabId: 11, windowId: 0 }
tabs.onHighlighted                ->  arg[0]= Object { tabIds: Array[1], windowId: 0 }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: undefined } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onZoomChange                 ->  arg[0]= Object { tabId: 11, oldZoomFactor: undefined, newZoomFactor: 1, zoomSettings: Object }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete", url: "about:blank" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: undefined } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "loading" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
tabs.onCreated                    ->  arg[0]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate    ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:blank", timeStamp: 1487871931270, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11 }
webNavigation.onErrorOccurred     ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:blank", timeStamp: 1487871931274, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, error: "Error code 2152398850", tabId: 11 }
webNavigation.onCommitted         ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:blank", timeStamp: 1487871931289, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, transitionType: "link", transitionQualifiers: Array[0] }
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate    ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487871931292, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11 }
webRequest.onBeforeRequest        ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "159", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487871931294, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11 }
webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders    ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "159", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487871931297, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, requestHeaders: Array[6] }
webRequest.onSendHeaders          ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "159", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487871931299, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, requestHeaders: Array[6] }
webRequest.onHeadersReceived      ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "159", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487871931312, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, responseHeaders: Array[11], 2 more… }
webRequest.onResponseStarted      ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "159", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487871931317, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, responseHeaders: Array[11], 2 more… }
webRequest.onCompleted            ->  arg[0]= Object { requestId: "159", url: "http://www.example.com/", originUrl: "http://www.example.com/", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1487871931329, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, responseHeaders: Array[11], 2 more… }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "loading", url: "http://www.example.com/" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
history.onVisited                 ->  arg[0]= Object { id: "fGv8w_MX50EI", url: "http://www.example.com/", title: "", lastVisitTime: 1487871931320, visitCount: 4, typedCount: 1 }
webNavigation.onCommitted         ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487871931480, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11, transitionType: "link", transitionQualifiers: Array[0] }
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 11 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 11, index: 2, windowId: 0, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1100, 5 more… }
webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded  ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487871931652, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11 }
webNavigation.onCompleted         ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "http://www.example.com/", timeStamp: 1487871931657, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 11 }
```

Comment: Full support for openerTabId is available from Firefox 57 onwards.

Comment: @Smile4ever Thanks. I updated this answer to reflect the current state of support.

Comment: note that openerTabId won't work when opening a tab in a different window, "The ID of the tab that opened this tab, if any. This property is only present if the opener tab still exists and **is in the same window.**"

Answer (score 2):

Firefox [now supports `tabs.Tab.openerTabId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab#Browser_compatibility) (it has been supported since Firefox 57 which was launched November 14, 2017)